# smtp php mailer not responding

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have wamp server2 but I installed phpmailer5 will it cause any problem?
my php.ini
I used [this site](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)

here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('./PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');
define('GUSER','phpmailer23@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD','mypass'); // GMail password
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
        global $error;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->Username = GUSER;
        $mail->Password = GPWD;
        $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
                $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
                return false;
        } else {
                $error = 'Message sent!';
                return true;
        }
}
smtpmailer('nickparsa@gmail.com','phpmailer23@gmail.com', 'phpmailer', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!');
if (smtpmailer('nickparsa@gmail.com','phpmailer23@gmail.com', 'phpmailer', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!')) {
    echo "sent";
}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

here is the output:

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mail error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

then I went to php.ini and set the smtpserver to smtp.google.com

```
SMTP = smtp.google.com
```

again no change

Comment: phpmailer doesn't use the php.ini mail settings. those are for Windows boxes which generally don't have a local MTA installed and have to use external services.

Comment: then what's the problem? before changing php.ini I had problem too

Comment: Try changing port to 465 instead of 25.

Comment: Also I don't see definition of GUSER and GPWD constants.

Comment: what are diffrences between smtp and gmail user? I can't understand clearly

Comment: changing the port didn't change anything too

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code (with port 465) and it works (I've sent it to nickparsa@gmail.com and phpmailer23@gmail.com so you can confirm it). You still have port 25 in code of your question so double check this. Also make sure you're giving right login and password.

Comment: Thanks But I am sure that I did the right,and the port 25 and 465 the both I tested and in the function smtpmailer I don't know why he got 6 inputs,but wrote this function with 5 inputs I think it is a mistake I tried 5 inputs without that empty input but no results